# Mongoose find all except one in aggregate users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
        User.aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "boughtitems", // collection name in db
                localField: "username",
                foreignField: "username",
                as: "boughtitems"
            }
        }]).then((users) => {
```

Can someone help me to write this code so that I can find all users except myself ? Every logged in users has it's own session so I can find them by `ID` like so: `User.findById(req.session.userId)`

Comment: What version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: Add `{$match:{_id: { $ne: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.session.userId)}}}` before $lookup stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [**`$ne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) aggregation operator

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(yourLoggedInId) }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "boughtitems",
    "localField": "username"
    "foreignField": "username",
    "as": "boughtitems"
  }}
])
```